# Inline function, always n+1 copies of code, where 'n' is number of calls

Tags: c++, c, optimization, inline

When I declare the inline function, it is copied and pasted into the places where it's called, and also there's one more copy, which we can jump to. Is it possible to stop it? I mean to have function code only in places when it's called. Not any more callable copies.

PS. I know that inline functions aren't always "inlined".

Answer (score 4):

If you don't take its address (either explicitly or implicitly), then there's no reason for the compiler to generate it out of line.

Answer (score 2):

If you define the function as `static inline` (C99) then no callable version will be generated. In fact if you don't call that function at all then it will not be included into your object file.